# Visual Studio not listing all modules

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio's not listing all our modules. We'd love some ideas why.

We're making a plugin that uses 3rd party software.

- Application (managed, not ours) lives in Program Files.
- our plugin (native) lives in a subdirectory.
- 3rd party software (native) lives in another subdirectory.

We do this:

- Launch from Visual Studio - the VS Module window lists everything.
- Attach To Process instead - the 3rd party libraries are missing from the Module window.
- Launch from Visual Studio, detach and reattach - the 3rd party libraries are again missing.

Tried:

- Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 - same thing with both.
- Process Explorer - 3rd party libraries are listed (and obvious in our plugin UI).
- A few machines - some work ok, others don't.

Our issue is that we're investigating hangs in the 3rd party software, but only outside the debugger!

Any ideas appreciated why the libraries are missing in Visual Studio, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for a couple of months and today I finally came across the solution.

It appears that there is a limit of module messages that the debugger can see when attaching to process and it's 500. The number can be increased by adding the following key to the registry. It increases the number to 2048.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager
 
DWORD DebuggerMaxModuleMsgs = 2048
```